# Grav CMS editor plugin for html tags as short codes in drop down menu (admin

Tags: html, plugins, module, shortcode, grav

I am wondering if there is any similar approach or plugin for Grav CMS as the one below for Processwire:

https://processwire.com/modules/process-hanna-code/

It fits fantastic for our setup. In another project based on Grav, we would need the same function now:

A drop down menu in the admin backend, where you edit page content, to include short codes. These codes represent html tags fetched via script from a remote API.

For now I just found this Plugin: https://getgrav.org/premium/nextgen-editor. I m not sure if it does the trick. We basically need just support for short-codes.

Does anyone know some plugins for Grav to achieve this? Thanks in advance for any hints.

Best, Markus

Comment: Did you have a look at https://github.com/getgrav/grav-plugin-shortcode-core? It does not provide a dropdown though. Does Hanna provide a dropdown?

Comment: For questions about next-gen-editor see https://github.com/getgrav/grav-premium-issues

Comment: Yes, Hanna Code provides a drop down. This would be necessary actually. Thanks @passerby, but I dont think that fits our need.